# How to publish raw data to /diagnostics topic?

Tags: ros, hardware, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been reading about [Diagnostics tools](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics)  in ROS and knew how to setup to analyze the raw data from robot hardware. But I'm wondering how to publish those data to /diagnostics topic, so that I can use them to analyze and re-publish to /diagnostics_agg topic?

Can anyone explain the process of getting raw data from robot hardware and how to config it to use in ROS? Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390851/how-to-publish-raw-data-to-/diagnostics-topic?/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out that first you need a code to read port signals (e.g. battety current or motor temperature), then publish those data to relevant topics. Once you have raw data in the system, you need a node to subscribe for those data and then reformat it to diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray type to republish them to /diagnostics topic so you can use it with the diagnostic package tools.

There is a really good example for filling the fields in DiagnosticArray type [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/262236/publishing-diagnostics-from-c/).

---

Originally posted by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) with karma: 58 on 2021-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish diagnostic information from your robot using the messages and services defined in [diagnostic_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_msgs). You should make a node that reads the raw data from the robot hardware and fills in these messages, then publishes them to the diagnostics topic.

There is a good tutorial on setting up the aggregator [available here](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Configuring%20Diagnostic%20Aggregators).

For a real example, see the [PR2 power board node](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_power_drivers/blob/9e5e7fc71545427b4007897eaa8c26c4e31681ec/pr2_power_board/src/power_node/power_node2.cpp#L589), which publishes diagnostic information for the power distribution board.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-11-15**:
Thank you for your answer. But I have to be honest, I'm not really good in coding, I got lost in the code you gave and didn't know where to start with. The only problem I have now is how to convert raw data to diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray, will I have to do it manually or is there a tool for the job? Since it quite an exhausting process.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-11-15**:
I can't tell you how to convert the raw data because I do not know what format it is in.

If you are struggling to understand the code, then I think you might be better off learning coding better first.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-11-15**:
For example, I received battery_voltage value from the hardware, so I want to re-format it as a DiagnosticArray message, with the 'name' field is "battery_voltage", and the 'value' field is the value of the battery voltage recieved, shoud I do it by re-format the data for every type of raw data, or is there another way to do it faster?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-11-16**:
That's how you have to do it.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-11-20**:
Okay, thanks for your enthusiasm.